# Create something like a timer using a while loop

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a while loop like this in my Console Application:

```
count = 0;
while (count < 60)
{
   count++; 
}
```

Okay so this loop runs very fast.

What i want is that it only adds `count++` maybe once every second.

Is this somehow possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Thread.Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
count = 0;
while (count < 60)
{
   Thread.Sleep(1000);  // waiting for 1 second
   count++; 
}
```

Comment: that worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Glad to have been of help